# PostgreSQL 11 UNNEST function does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run the very last example from Table 7.49 in section 9.18. Array Functions and Operators [1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1,2],ARRAY['foo','bar','baz']);
```

and it throws this error:

> [42883] ERROR: function unnest(integer[], text[]) does not exist
>
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might
>   need to add explicit type casts.

According to the results columns in table 7.49, it should give me:

```
--------------
| 1    | foo |
--------------
| 2    | bar |
--------------
| NULL | baz |
--------------
```

Is there something I missed in my configuration setup to cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2],ARRAY['foo','bar','baz']);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bd392427d2114e3d80f61dea3c66fabc)**